# How to get the time difference betwwe timePicker and System Time

Tags: android

i want to make a small alarm application. i want to calculate the time difference between the system time (current) and the time From `TimePicker`(chosen by user). i could not find  some good solution. here is my code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_list);
    timePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker1);
    timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    c = Calendar.getInstance();
    timePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(new OnTimeChangedListener() {





    @Override
    public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker arg0, int hours, int minutes) {
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minutes);

        chosenTimeMills = c.getTimeInMillis();
    }
});


b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                          Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
                c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,currentDate.getHours());
                c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, currentDate.getMinutes());
                systemTimeMills = c.getTimeInMillis();

                long difference  =systemTimeMills-chosenTimeMills;
                Date date = new Date(difference);
                Log.d("TAGG", "Difference is: "+date.getHours()+" Hours and "+date.getMinutes()+" minutes");



    }
});
}
```

I Would love to have an answer. Thanks,Usman!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
c2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22);
c2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
long sub = c2.getTimeInMillis() - c.getTimeInMillis();
```

here `c` is the `Calender` instance that you have created and `c2` will b instance for current `date time`.

---

**Edit**

In the `onClick` you can try

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
long diff = c.getTimeInMillis() - cal.getTimeInMillis();
long diffInSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diff);
int hour = (int) (diffInSec / (60 * 60));
int minremaining = (int) (diffInSec % (60 * 60));
int min = (int) (minremaining / (60));
int secondsRemaining = (int) (minremaining % (60));
Log.e("TAG", "Difference in    milliss   calendar      " + diff);
Log.e("TAG", "hour      " + hour);
Log.e("TAG", "min       " + min);
Log.e("TAG", "sec       " + secondsRemaining);
```

Where `c` is the `Calendar` instance with the value, set in `onTimeChanged`

The variable `hour`, `min` and `secondsRemaining` will give you the remaining amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is when you use a `TimePicker`you have only access to the *Hour and Minute*.
I am suposing that you want the difference, currentSystemTime and TodayTime + Hour and Minute.

For instance:
If the user pick 20:35 at 10:00(currentTime), you should get **10:35**. Correct?

So here is my solution(Full example here: [Github full example](http://github.com/androidzin/android-examples)):

```
@Override
public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    pickedHour = hourOfDay;
    pickedMinute = minute;
}

public void onClickListenerOfYourBUtton(View view)
{
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long diffTime = 0;

    calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    sysCurrent.setText(currentTime +"");

    calendar.setTimeInMillis(currentTime);//set to currentTime to know the current day
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, pickedHour); 
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, pickedMinute);

    diffTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis()- currentTime; // Here, i get the difference in hours, minutes, ...for the same day



    difference.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d",
            diffTime/hoursInMilis, 
            (diffTime%hoursInMilis)/minutesInMilis)); //Formating string




}
```

Answer (score 1):

well , you get system time in Millis . and convert your picked time in millis , and just take a difference of it .

Comment: my system time is in 12hours format and picked time is in 24hours, would this be causing me trouble  or not  ?

Comment: no it won't , both will be numbers like 123456789 . it's total time in milliseconds.